# Difference between byte code .<init>()V vs .<init>(Z)V

Tags: java, bytecode

When I observe my Java project byte code, I see the following byte code :

**java.lang.Object.()V**

**java.lang.Boolean.(Z)V**

What is the meaning of **<init>()V** and **<init>(Z)V**

Answer (score 15):

> ```
> java.lang.Object.()V
> ```

is a void method (`V`) on `java.lang.Object` that takes no arguments.

> ```
> java.lang.Boolean.(Z)V
> ```

is a void method on `java.lang.Boolean` that takes a single `boolean` (`Z` since `B` is `byte`) argument.

In short,

```
 abc.def.WXYZ(IIIIIIIIIIIIII)J
 ^            ^              ^ 
 target_class argument-types return_type
```

See [JNI Type Signatures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432) for more detail.

> The JNI uses the Java VM’s representation of type signatures. Table 3-2 shows these type signatures.
>
> Table 3-2 Java VM Type Signatures
>
> ```
> Type Signature             Java Type
> Z                          boolean
> B                          byte
> ...
> L fully-qualified-class ;  fully-qualified-class
> [ type                      type[]
> ( arg-types ) ret-type      method type
> ```
>
> For example, the Java method:
>
> ```
> long f (int n, String s, int[] arr);
> ```
>
> has the following type signature:
>
> ```
> (ILjava/lang/String;[I)J
> ```

Answer (score 4):

It's all method signatures in bytecode used by JVM.

`<init>()V and <init>(Z)V` are construtor signatures. For JVM constructors are just as any other methods, they have a name, which is always `<init>`), and a return value, which is always `V` (means void).  In our case `Z` means `boolean` parameter (`B` is reserved for `byte`)

that is

```
<init>(Z)V
```

in class Test's bytecode means

```
class Test {

    Test(boolean arg0) {
    }
}
```

you can also meet

```
 static <clinit>()V
```

which means static initialization block

```
static {
...
}
```